# Generate a dictionary key for every multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to use multiprocessing and generate a key for every process.

The outcome would be:

```
data={
  'Data'=['One','Two','Three']
  1=['a','b','c']
  2=['a','b','c']
  ...
}
```

This is my code:

```
import multiprocessing

data={
        'Data':['One','Two','Three']
}

def main():
    for i in range(3):
        p=multiprocessing.Process(target=generate, args=[i])
        p.start()

    processes=[]
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

def generate(key):
    data[key]=['a','b','c']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So basically:

1. Create the loop to generate the multiprocess
2. Send the value to generate the key

What do I need to do to get the desire outcome?

Thank you!

Comment: it’s dangerous to have multiple processes modifying a mutable object with no synchronization

Comment: Your desire outcome isn't a valid Python data-structure.

Comment: Assuming `data` is supposed to be a (shared) dictionary, you're going to need to use a [`multiprocessing.Manager()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) to control concurrent access to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running two separate processes, then they won't be sharing the same globals.
If you want to pass the data between the processes, look at using send and recv. 
Take a look at http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes